# Prefabs en Unity 2019.3.6f1

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d

tengo un problema, estoy elaborando un juego en 2D pero a la hora de crear un prefab no me da la opcion en unity 2019.3.6f1 y al tenerlo desactualizado al 2017 si me daba la opción, ¿sera problema de la nueva versión?¿Tengo que instalar una extensión?, necesito crear los prefabs alguien que me diga como, les agradezco su ayuda ya que no encuentro nada por Internet. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es muy amplia, como estas tratando de crear el prefab?

Generalmente  para crear un prefab puedes crear un objecto en el escenario y después arrastrar y soltar el objeto a la carpeta que deseas, debería funcionar.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera puede ser, en la zona de proyecto seleccionar la carpeta en la que quieres almacenar el prefab, dar click derecho en el interior -> create->prefab.